# How to configure query's pagination parameters in MS Teams Search Based Messaging Extension request?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using MS teams search based messaging extension.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet#default-query
In the deafault query I get -  "queryOptions": {
"skip": 0,
"count": 25
}

Is there any way to customise this count.

Comment: What would you like to change?

Comment: I want to change the count, So in the request i get, "queryOptions": { "skip": 0, "count": 10}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any supporting document to update the `queryOptions` but you can handle it in your code manually and set how many items you want to show initially and how many when you search something. When messaging extension is run initially, query parameter name is set to `"initialRun"`, so here how you can use it

```
if (query.Parameters[0].Name == "initialRun")
{
    // Write the code handling number of results to be return.
}
else
{
    // Write the code handling number of results to be return when user search.
}
```

Thanks